# Very Strange behavior in custom dataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have a dataGrid with a custom itemRenderer. Everytime I tab at least two times on the dataGrid, the cell below the one I taped gets selected. This doesn't happen if I uncomment the code in the method saveBackDataGridContent()!

The second problem is that if the Line is shorter than the entered text, a horizontalScrollBar will get active, although I set setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", "off");... (update: this issue got solved see below!)

Who can solve that one?

> CustomRenderer.mxml:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" initialize="dataService.send()">
 <mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   import components.ChoiceRenderer;
   import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
   import mx.events.DataGridEvent;

       private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void {   
        var doc:XML = event.result as XML;
        testGrid.dataProvider = doc.Records.BackSide;   
       }


      private function saveBackDataGridContent(event:DataGridEvent):void{        
       testGrid.dataProvider[event.rowIndex].TextElement = event.currentTarget.itemEditorInstance.text;         
      }    

   ]]>
 </mx:Script>
 <mx:HTTPService id="dataService" result="resultHandler(event)" url = "data/example.xml" resultFormat="e4x"/>

 <mx:DataGrid id="testGrid" editable="true" itemEditEnd="saveBackDataGridContent(event)">
       <mx:columns>
         <mx:DataGridColumn itemRenderer="components.ChoiceRenderer" width="230"/>
      </mx:columns>
 </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

> ChoiceRenderer.as

```
    package components
    {
     import mx.containers.HBox;
     import mx.controls.CheckBox;
     import mx.controls.Label;

     public class ChoiceRenderer extends HBox
     {

      private var correctAnswer:CheckBox;
      private var choiceLabel:Label;

      public function ChoiceRenderer()
      {
       super();              
       setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", "off");
       correctAnswer = new CheckBox;
       addChild(correctAnswer);   
       choiceLabel = new Label;
       addChild(choiceLabel);  
      }

         override public function set data(xmldata:Object):void{
          if(xmldata.name() == "BackSide"){
           super.data = xmldata.TextElement[0];
           choiceLabel.text = xmldata.TextElement[0].toString();
          }
         }
     }
    }
```

> example.xml

```
<TopContainer>
 <Records>
  <BackSide>
   <TextElement>first</TextElement>             
  </BackSide>
  <BackSide>
   <TextElement>second</TextElement>            
  </BackSide>
  <BackSide>
   <TextElement>third</TextElement>             
  </BackSide>
  <BackSide>
   <TextElement>fourth</TextElement>            
  </BackSide>
  <BackSide>
   <TextElement>fifth</TextElement>            
  </BackSide>
  <BackSide>
   <TextElement>sixth</TextElement>            
  </BackSide>
 </Records>
</TopContainer>
```

I can't believe, that this problem is such a big of a thing, but I coudln't find any solution so far... Isn't this a standard function what I'm trying to do?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: Markus, rather than double posting in the future, know that when you edit a question it bumps it back to the top of the list. This is usually a better option as people would be able to see what hasn't been working. I would recommend removing this question and instead editing your old one.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand your point!

Comment: You might get more help if you were able to simplify the example to something we could just copy and paste and run on our side. (shoot for something we can copypaste into just the application mxml file and immediately run to see your problem) All this example code you provide is confusing to follow and would probably not work if we tried to compile it on our machines (ie missing componenets or data sources). I've given you all the help I can without actually poking around in the code, but not even for 100 rep am I going to spend the 45 min it would take just to get your example to compile.

Answer (score 2):

The question your posing is rather huge, but some pointers that may be giving you trouble.

ItemRenderers are recycled. This may be one of your problems, you need to make sure that any if statements in your itemRenderer also has an else statement (which would set it back to it's default state). This is a common pitfall when working with renderers.

this line `setStyle("horizontalScrollPolicy", "off");` won't work because horizontalScrollPolicy is a property, not a style.

Fix these situations and then see where you are at.

Also read this article:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html

And this one:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt2.html

They were instrumental in helping me understand item renderers and their many quirks.

Comment: Thanks for your help! the horizontalScrollPolicy issue is solved now... but the other problem wasn't solved with a additional else statement...

Comment: maybe you need to add this to your renderer `override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void{ super.updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight );` It will help if the problem is the recycling.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help neither... As soon as I change the xml data behind the list, the mentioned behavior will occur

Comment: I'm at a loss then :(    Maybe try binding an XML var to your dataGrid, and instead of re-assigning the dataprovider in your result handler, just update that var with the result handler, improper binding seems like it might cause an issue like that.

Comment: You mean to replace the code in the result handler with: doc.Records.BackSide[event.rowIndex].TextElement = event.currentTarget.itemEditorInstance.text; 
statement? That didn't solve it neither...

Comment: I think the change needs to be bigger than that. You would need to start by declaring an XMLListCollection, binding your dataGrids DP to it, then in your result handler modify what's happening to update that XMLListCollection.

Comment: I did that but unfortunately with no success... really strange!